# Microsoft Edge window.open() not honoring width height, and opens in background

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm on Windows 10 preview Build 10130, and the `window.open` method in the new Edge browser isn't behaving as per the specification.

If you use the example code in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx, and click to open a new window, it will open a new window in the background, and will completely ignore the width and height.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>window.open()</title>
      <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onclick="myOpen();">
      <p>Click this page and window.open() is called.</p>
      <script>
        function myOpen() {
          window.open("Sample.htm", null, "height=200, width=400, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no");
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Anyone else see this issue? http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/c91hcoum/2/

Comment: Report it to Microsoft?

Comment: Just did. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1400158/microsoft-edge-window-open-not-honoring-width-height-and-opens-in-background

Comment: @Sudi Thank you. I work on the Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge team. I'll investigate this further and ensure that it gets attention on our end.

Comment: Reporting back that this functionality is now *fixed* in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I've confirmed that build 10162 resolves this issue

Comment: unfortunately, this is not fixed completely. Now, opening the window works correctly the first time, but the next time onwards, there's a blue screen with a e.

Comment: Broken again? I'm using Edge 25.10586.0.0 and it is not honoring the width and height (Win 10 1511 build 10586.104).

Comment: Seems like I have the same issue as @WillFastie. Same version of Edge (25.10586.0.0), Windows 10 1511 build 10586.318

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now resolved in windows build 10162

Comment: Please accept this answer so that users know the solution (upgrade to build 10162+)!

Comment: Accepted with one [caveat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416155/microsoft-edge-window-open-only-works-correctly-at-first-attempt?lq=1).

Comment: Not resolved - https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1400158/microsoft-edge-window-open-not-honoring-width-height-and-opens-in-background

Answer (score 1):

The open method documentation and sample code in the URL you shared is aimed at IE and has not been updated yet for Edge. As i have noticed while reading through that page. Edge is still being polished and refined while we are in the insider preview mode. 
On Build 10162, I got it working here on this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/wu09fh1d/

`window.open("http://dev.modern.ie/community/","_blank","height=500,width=500,scrollbars=yes,location=yes");`

you can see the window opening with height 500, width 300 with a scroll bar, mini-maximize and close button. 
Check the screenshot below.

[image]

`window.open("http://dev.modern.ie/community/","_blank","height=500,width=500,scrollbars=yes,location=yes");`

Answer (score -1):

If the height is higher than the screen (including the browser fluff), the window will be maximized.  This is different than the behavior using IE 9, 10, 11.

This is with RTM Win10 Edge.