# Opening a new window using window.open in Microsoft Edge isn't working

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

When using window.open with below given code, there is issue in closing the Window, Minimizing the window, and maximizing the window.

```
window.open(url, '_blank', "height=" + winH + ",width=" + winW + ",fullscreen=yes");
```

After pressing `win+D` (minimizing all windows), and opening only the new window, the above mentioned buttons (Minimize, Maximize, Close) were working.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30582414/54680) the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: @avk87 I created a jsfiddle that shows this in action in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

On Build 10162, I got it working here on this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/wu09fh1d/

```
window.open("http://dev.modern.ie/community/","_blank","height=500,width=500,scrollbars=yes,location=yes");
```

you can see the window opening with height 500, width 300 with a scroll bar, mini-maximize and close button. Check the screenshot below.
[image]