# how to open web browser in IE 11 using window.open

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

is there a way to open web browser in IE 11?

First, I checked the browser version that is 'microsoft edge' or not.
And then, if the browser is 'microsoft edge', I wanna open new window in IE 11 by using window.open.
Is it possible?

[Here is a sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/hsseo/s46L44ad/5/)

```
function checkVersion() { 
    //i wanna open new window in IE11.
    //window.open('www.google.com');
}
```

Is there way to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a new window using window.open in Microsoft Edge isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635314/opening-a-new-window-using-window-open-in-microsoft-edge-isnt-working)

Comment: I try. but the browser is open in window edge.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe this blog post may help you: http://blogs.technet.com/b/brandonlinton/archive/2015/08/01/how-to-force-microsoft-edge-to-open-the-application-catalog-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I am understanding correctly.

If someone is using Microsoft Edge, then you want to use JavaScript to open a new browser window in Internet Explorer 11. In other words, you want to switch browsers.

Is that right?

You will not be able to do this in MS Edge.

You would need to use something like Active X or Browser Helper Objects which [are not part of MS Edge](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/). Here is [an example of you would have done it with ActiveX](http://forums.asp.net/t/1652038.aspx?How%20can%20we%20force%20a%20link%20to%20open%20a%20URL%20in%20a%20different%20browser%20).