# Microsoft Edge: window.open only works correctly at first attempt

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

In MS Edge (windows 10 build 10162), window.open call only works correctly the first time, but subsequent window.open calls only shows a blue screen with the e logo.

```
<body onclick="myOpen();">
    <p>Click this page and window.open() is called.</p>
    <script>
        function myOpen() {
            window.open("http://jsfiddle.net/sbhat/f74wt293/", null, "height=200, width=400, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbhat/f74wt293/1/
Click on the page, close the pop up window, and click on it again. There's a blue screen.

[image]

I filed another issue with window.open described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582414/microsoft-edge-window-open-not-honoring-width-height-and-opens-in-background/31279600#31279600), which appeared fixed at first, now I've run into this issue.

Comment: Also submitted https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1546067

Comment: So.. what are you asking?

Comment: This issue appears to be fixed/resolved in Windows 10 Build 10240. (edited because the OP clearly mentioned their build.)

Comment: This is indeed fixed in build 10240.

Comment: How can we pass some string value to that window? Can you please answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947586/pass-custom-arguments-to-window-open-in-case-of-edge-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer an issue, this is fixed in windows 10 preview build 10240

Comment: How can we pass some string value to that window? Can you please answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947586/pass-custom-arguments-to-window-open-in-case-of-edge-browser

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is only partially correct. Build 10240 corrects the blank box when you open a window for the second time.  However, new popup windows still open BEHIND the main browser window around 50% of the time. ie they do not automatically get focus. You only know they are there because the Edge icon on the task bar flashes.

Comment: Hi Nick . Even i face the same issue . Any update from Microsoft or workaround you did ?

Answer (score 1):

On Build 10162, I got it working here on this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/wu09fh1d/2/

```
<a href="#" onclick="openUp()">Click this page and window.open() is called.</a>    
<button onclick="openUp()">Click me</button>

function openUp() {
    window.open("http://dev.modern.ie/community/", "_blank", "height=200,width=400,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,location=no");
}
```

you can see the window opening more than once and you can run the script and click multiple times and it still pops up
[image]

Comment: See the blue screen with the e instead of the real window? That's my problem.

Comment: Hi @Sudi i updated the image. you can see the popups working just fine. check it out on the JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your window `name` upon each open.

```
window.open(myURL, 'my_window_' + Math.random())
```

Comment: Why would you use Math.random for this? What happens when you "randomly" select a number that was already used for a previously/still open window? And how would the intended effect be any different than using _blank?

Comment: using new names prevents the browser from reusing old windows. Your chances of getting the same number are 1 in 1,000,000,000,000,000. Using `_blank` as a name on subsequent call will reuse an old blank window.

Comment: But why math.Random? Couldn't you seed from the date/time and guarantee a different name every time? And do you have a source that supports your last sentence? _blank never recycles windows for me.

Comment: Sorry - and yeah you're right. (+new Date) would be a simpler solution and cleaner.